# Android Studio how to jump to method definitions using breadcrumbs like xCode?

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, project-navigator

I'm looking for a way to jump to a method definition within a .java file using Android Studio. I know that xCode has a breadcrumb path like in the image below which ends in the method and instance variables.

**How can I jump to a method definition in Android Studio?**

[image]

Comment: How about Ctrl+LMB on a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the left-hand bar, you might have:

- 1 - Project
- 2 - Favourites
- 7 - Structure

What you want is "Structure" tab, which will show you a list of methods, variables etc. You can also right-click on it and customise, eg. to sort by visibility, alphabetically, which items to show etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They IntelliJ [shortcut map](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf) has it listed as control + up/down. I havent been able to get this to work on my Mac though because the OS wants to use the same shortcuts for displaying your desktops and all windows in a program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Structure Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html) (⌘ + 7 or ⌘ + F12). to view a list of namespaces, classes, methods, and functions in the current file.  Additionally, you can turn on display for class fields, inherited members, and included files.